# Does autodiff in tensorflow work if I have a for loop involved in constructing my graph?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, autodiff

I have a situation where I have a batch of images and in each image I have to perform some operation over a tiny patch in that image. Now the problem is the patch size is variable in each image in the batch. So this implies that I cannot vectorize it. I could vectorize by considering the entire range of pixels in an image but my patch size per image is really a small fraction and I don't want to waste my memory here by performing the operation and storing the results for all the pixels in each image.

So in short, I need to use a loop. Now I see that tensorflow has just a while loop defined and no for loops. So my question is , if I use a plain python style for loop for performing operations over my tensor , will the autodiff fail to calculate gradients in my graph?

Comment: should be ok, although the graph will be larger (there's 2GB graph size limit)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov , Thanks for your reply! Two followup questions - a. 2GB size ; is it for the entire graph or for a single tensor (a node) in the graph? b. If a normal for loop works , then is there a reason that tensor-flow introduced a tf.while_loop? Is it just to make things more efficient on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow does not know (thus does not care) how the graph has been constructed, you can even write each node by hand as long as you use proper functions to do so. So in particular for loop has nothing to do with TF. TF while loop on the other hand gives you ability to express dynamic computations inside the graph, so if you want to process data in a sequence and only need a current one in the memory - only while loop can achieve that. If you create a huge graph by hand (through the loop) it will be always executed, and everything stored in memory. As long as this fits on your machine you should be fine. Another thing is the dynamic length, if sometimes you need to run a loop 10 times, and sometimes 1000, you have to use tf.while_loop, you cannot do this with for loop (unless you create separate graphs for each possible length).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! Makes more sense now as to why tensorflow has provided a tf.while_loop.